# how to use trunc date() function in oracle.?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When I run following query I got error.Can Someone help me to solve this.

```
 select trunc('27-oct-97','dd-mm-yy') form dual;
```

when I run this query i got following error:

> Error:inline number function.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm

Comment: `trunc()` applies to numbers and dates. What you have there is a *string*.

Comment: Also, why are you using 2 digit years? Years have 4 digits; why make Oracle guess when you can be specific? Would '49 refer to 1949 or 2049?

Answer (score 5):

The [`TRUNC` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) has the signature:

```
TRUNC( date_value, format )
```

You are providing a string value instead of a date value and `'dd-mm-yy'` is an [invalid format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084) (you just want to truncate to the start of the day using `'dd'` as the format or the start of the month using `'mm'` or the start of the year using `'yy'` - but using all three together does not make sense).

You can use ANSI date literals to specify the date:

```
SELECT TRUNC(
         DATE '1997-10-27',
         'DD'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

Or use the `TO_DATE` function:

```
SELECT TRUNC(
         TO_DATE( '27-oct-97', 'DD-MON-RR' ),
         'DD'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

*(and you can also omit the `'DD'` format argument as the default is to truncate to the start of the day.)*

But, in both cases, the truncation is redundant as the date's time component is already midnight so does not need truncating.

What you want is a date value that has a non-midnight time component:

```
SELECT TRUNC(
         TO_DATE( '1997-10-27 12:34:56', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ),
         'DD'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

or to truncate to the start of the month or year:

```
SELECT TRUNC(
         DATE '1997-10-27',
         'MM'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Remove the time portion from the date truncate into the nearest date:

```
TRUNC(DATE)
```

2) Use format, to specify which values to trunc:

```
TRUNC(DATE,year)
```

Truncates (will turn to 1) everything that is before the format , in this example the year.
So this:

```
trunc(to_date('27-oct-97','dd-mm-yy'),'YEAR')
```

Will output this:

```
01-jan-97
```